# Вырезать текст от первого до последнего символа

Tags: php

Есть ссылка: http://site.ru/test/folder/photo/ph-1.png

Каким образом получить из этой ссылки только: **test/folder/photo**

То есть, мне нужно то что идет после **//** и до последнего **/**

Comment: Это `только: test/folder/photo` и это `после // и до последнего /` противоречат друг другу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вручную вырезать то, что нужно.

```
$str = 'http://site.ru/test/folder/photo/ph-1.png';
$parts = explode('/', $str);
$path = implode('/', array_slice($parts, 3, -1));
echo $path; // test/folder/photo
echo implode('/', array_slice($parts, 2, -1)); // site.ru/test/folder/photo
```

[Демонстрация](https://3v4l.org/NDKgW)

Answer (score 4):

Можете использовать `parse_url`

```
$url = 'http://site.ru/test/folder/photo/ph-1.png';
   $data = parse_url($url); 
   print_r($data );
```

получится на выходе

```
Array ( [scheme] => http [host] => site.ru [path] => /test/folder/photo/ph-1.png )
```

> Обновлено

```
$clearArray = explode('/',$data['path']);
array_pop($clearArray);
$implodeData = implode('/',$clearArray);
print_r($implodeData);
```

Comment: Но мне не нужно **/ph-1.png**

Comment: как вариант можете split() полученную строку разбить и собрать новую.

Comment: @Alex.B а не проще регуляркой?

Comment: @Денис обновил ответ, думаю должно помочь, слегка длинно получилось )

Comment: если проще, составьте)

Answer (score 2):

Дополню ответ @Arsen

После парсинга url

```
$url = 'http://site.ru/test/folder/photo/ph-1.png';
$data = parse_url($url);
```

можно написать так:

```
$str = data['path'];
echo trim(substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, '/')), "/");
```

что там написано:

**[strrpos](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strrpos.php)** - возвращает позицию последнего вхождения подстроки в строке

**[substr](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php)** - возвращает подстроку строки string, начинающейся с start символа по счету и длиной length символов

**[trim](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.trim.php)** - удаляет пробелы (или другие символы) из начала и конца строки. Вторым параметром можно передать   набор символов, которые можно обрезать.

Answer (score 2):

```
$str='http://site.ru/test/folder/photo/ph-1.png';
preg_match_all('|.*//(.*)/.*|i',$str,$res);
print_r($res);
```

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => http://site.ru/test/folder/photo/ph-1.png ) [1] => Array ( [0] => site.ru/test/folder/photo ) )

Comment: `|//(.*)/|` достаточно.

Comment: @Visman `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => //site.ru/test/folder/photo/ ) [1] => Array ( [0] => site.ru/test/folder/photo ) )`

Comment: и `preg_match()`.

Comment: Да, так даже ответ короче... `Array ( [0] => //site.ru/test/folder/photo/ [1] => site.ru/test/folder/photo )`